# How do you edit the settings you entered when you registered your Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do you edit the settings you entered when you registered your Facebook app?
I need to change the base url and cannot for the life of me figure it out navigating the site.
Someone must know where this is accessible.

**Edit:**
Hmmm, guess I have been going to the right place, right now I just get
'An error occurred with Developer. Please try again later.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link is: http://www.facebook.com/developers/editapp.php?app_id=[APP_ID]
You can navigate to this link starting from [facebook.com/developers](http://www.facebook.com/developers). The base URL can be edited inside the Facebook integration tab (on the left)

Answer (score 2):

From the right sidebar My Apps on the [developers](http://www.facebook.com/developers/) page

Answer (score 0):

http://www.facebook.com/developers

Find your app on the right, then go to Edit Settings.

Comment: Ahm, when I go there I get 'An error occurred with Developer. Please try again later.'

Answer (score 0):

Just as an FYI... my app doesn't show up under the developer page (yes, I'm logged in) and if I use the URL that jack provided I just get redirected to my account/info page.

My app works but it can't be edited...